# java.lang.StackOverflowError issue with Lambda and recursion

Tags: java, recursion, lambda

When I use the old fashion list.iterator() for doing recursion on directory the below code works, but I don't understand the the cause of stackoverflow which appears only when I use lambda as per Java 8 style.

```
private void walk(File file, int depth) {
    if (depth >= maxDepth)
        return;     
    List<File> files = file.isDirectory()?Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()):Arrays.asList(file);
    filesStream.addAll(files.stream()
                        .filter(predicate1.and(predicate2))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    Stream<File> filteredDirectories = files.stream()
                                            .filter(predicate3.and(predicate4));
    int currentDepth = ++depth;
    filteredDirectories.forEach(f -> walk(f, currentDepth));
}
```

Below is the stacktrace

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.Collection.stream(Collection.java:581)
at org.util.DirectoryManager.walk(DirectoryManager.java:192)
at org.util.DirectoryManager.lambda$12(DirectoryManager.java:198)
at org.util.DirectoryManager$$Lambda$10/1068824137.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.util.DirectoryManager.walk(DirectoryManager.java:198)
at org.util.DirectoryManager.lambda$12(DirectoryManager.java:198)
at org.util.DirectoryManager$$Lambda$10/1068824137.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.util.DirectoryManager.walk(DirectoryManager.java:198)
at org.util.DirectoryManager.lambda$12(DirectoryManager.java:198)
at org.util.DirectoryManager$$Lambda$10/1068824137.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
...
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.util.DirectoryManager.walk(DirectoryManager.java:198)
at org.util.DirectoryManager.lambda$12(DirectoryManager.java:198)
at org.util.DirectoryManager$$Lambda$10/1068824137.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
```

Comment: I'm confused why you do `files.stream().filter(predicate1.and(predicate2))` twice

Comment: what is the value of `maxDepth`, and why do you use `Arrays.asList(file)` for single file? this clearly will cause the recursion to be called with the same parameter all over again

Comment: "As a alternative" to what? What are  you trying to *do*? Because you're basically asking an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) here.

Comment: Why not using Files API which remove most of this boiler plate : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...- or https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor- ?

Answer (score 1):

You recurse infinitely. If `file` isn't a directory, you still walk it again. Check that `file` is a directory first, something like,

```
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    Stream<File> filteredDirectories = files.stream()
            .filter(predicate1.and(predicate2));
    int currentDepth = ++depth;
    filteredDirectories.forEach(f -> walk(f, currentDepth));
}
```

Comment: I've never seen "recurse" hyphenated.

Comment: Unless you're talking about someone continually swearing